# How to explain the following discrepency when changing parameter for exponential?

Tags: chi-squared-test, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution, sum

Suppose $y$~ $\exp(\frac{1}{2\theta})$

then $\frac1\theta y$~$\exp(\frac12)=\frac14\chi^2_2=\frac14\gamma(1,2)$

then $\sum \frac1\theta y=\frac14\chi^2_{2n}$

then $\sum y$~$ \frac{\theta}{4} \chi^2_{2n}$

However if I go the other way:

$\frac1\theta\frac12 y$~$\exp(1)=\frac12\chi^2_2=\frac12\gamma(1,2)$

then $\sum \frac{1}{2\theta} y=\frac12\chi^2_{2n}$

then $\sum y$~$ \theta \chi^2_{2n}$

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is in the first row of the derivation. The χ2(2) distribution is the same as an exponential distribution with parameter 1/2 (mean 2). Therefore, the 1/4 with which you multiplied the χ2(2) should not be there.

Comment: We are talking about rate right? so $\exp(\frac12)=\gamma(1,\frac12)$ where $\frac12$ is rate. But then why $\exp(1)=\frac12\chi^2_2=\frac12\gamma(1,\frac12)$?

Comment: What exactly is your question? The rate is the rate at which the exponential random variable ends, and so a higher rate implies shorter values of the variable. An exponential random variable with rate 1 will have an average (1) which is half of the average of an exponential random variable with rate 1/2 (2).